# Python Non-ASCII character Error

Tags: python

I Have a written a small python code with intention of getting my system information and disk size. I am using subprocess module here.

```
[root@localhost code]# cat pysys.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess;

def sysinfo():
        subprocess.call(“uname –a”,shell=True)
def diskinfo():
        subprocess.call(“df –h”,shell=True)
def main():
        sysinfo()
        diskinfo()
main()
```

When ever I am trying to execute , I am getting the error as

```
[root@localhost code]# python pysys.py
  File "pysys.py", line 5
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file pysys.py on line 5, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
[root@localhost code]#
```

EDIT:

```
[root@localhost code]# cat pysys.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess;

def sysinfo():
        subprocess.call("uname –a",shell=True)
def diskinfo():
        subprocess.call("df –h",shell=True)
def main():
        sysinfo()
        diskinfo()
main()

[root@localhost code]# python pysys.py
  File "pysys.py", line 5
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file pysys.py on line 5, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
[root@localhost code]#
```

Am I missing anything ? Please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using non-ASCII character.(`–` / `’`). It usually happens when you copy content from somewhere.

So modify your code as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess;

def sysinfo():
        subprocess.call("uname -a",shell=True)
def diskinfo():
        subprocess.call("df -h",shell=True)
def main():
        sysinfo()
        diskinfo()
main()
```

**The difference is just `-`. You are using `–`.**

Answer (score 3):

Your quotes look weird, use shift-2 and nothing else, i.e. a `"`

ascii 34, hex 22, octal 042

If you are using vim as your editor, you can check value under cursor using `ga`

Comment: shift-2 is only `"` on some keyboards.  On US keyboards shift-2 is `@` and the `"` is over next to the return key.

Comment: Yea yea rub it in. That's why I posted the ascii-values (2 out of 3 wasn't that bad) ;-)